# Stop Data mining on Private Blockchain running on Etherrum platform

Tags: blockchain, mining, private

We have setup a private blockchain platform using Ethereum and we are using Java based UI layer for it. Can we stop mining process as it is taking lots of time and making the transactions slow?

Comment: Have you considered using a non-Proof of Work network type instead? For example, POA https://wiki.parity.io/Proof-of-Authority-Chains

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stop the mining process. If you stop mining no new blocks will be generated. From the geth console you can execute:

```
> miner.stop()
```

Check the documentation for details [`miner.stop()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#miner_stop).

In a private blockchain you can control how many thread are used for mining with 
[`miner.start()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#miner_start). For example to only use 1 thread from the geth console type:

```
> miner.start(1)
```